# export friend from template to global namespace

Tags: c++, templates

Is any way to export friend from template to global namespace without forward declaration?

```
template <typename T>
struct flags {
    static_assert(std::is_enum_v<T>);

    using base = std::underlying_type_t<T>;

    friend T operator|(const T lhs, const T rhs) {
        return T(base(lhs) | base(rhs));
    }
};

enum class MyEnum {
    A,
    B
};

template struct flags<MyEnum>;

auto operator|(MyEnum, MyEnum) -> MyEnum; // (1)

MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum::A | MyEnum::B; //Not compile without (1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying that it is a nice and imaginative idea for code generation. But there is no way to expose the friend function for argument dependent lookup.

The problem is that ADL only considers friends of associated namespaces and class types. For an enumeration to be associated with a class type, it must be a member of the class, i.e. a member of a `flags` specialization. There is no way to associate an enum with a class type (for ADL purposes) otherwise.

In your use case the enumeration is obviously not intended to be a member of `flags<MyEnum>`, so friend functions of `flags<MyEnum>` are not going to be considered in overload resolution that involves just `MyEnum`.

Comment: I had a similar issue with this; I ended up just placing my templates in the global namespace. Is that problematic?

Comment: @Robbie - Yes, very. Unconstrained templated in global scope is a recepie for conflicting overloads at some point.

Comment: I used concepts to constraint them with a void Tag (It must be explicitly enabled to work). Does that lower the concern? If not, is there any workaround for this at the moment?

Comment: @Robbie - So the tag is specialized to explicitly opt-in? Nice. No obvious problem comes to mind with that detail. My old goto way of doing it in the past was to define the overloads in a dedicated `util` namespace. Then use a macro (I know, sad) as a shorthand  to bring a bunch of using declarations (`using util::operator|;`, etc) into the target namespace of the enum. A using declaration counts as a namespace member for ADL. So a simple `USE_UTIL_ENUM_OPS;` pulled them in with the enum they could operate on.

Comment: @Robbie - Of course, my problem with macros is that I then try to be fancy... https://wandbox.org/permlink/o6A2pRD8x2Fu7UsS