# Generating comparison operators without CRTP

Tags: c++, templates

Let's consider class like that with `less than` operator:

```
struct Test
{
    int value;
    constexpr bool operator<(const Test& p_rhs) const
    {
        return value < p_rhs.value;
    }
};
```

I would like to generate `bool operator>(const Test&, const Test&)`,`bool operator<=(const Test&, const Test&)` and `bool operator>=(const Test&, const Test&)` without using CRTP(or any other inheritance) on `Test` class on generic way, that could be also used on other classes that have `bool operator<(const T&,const T&)`. I tried sth like that:

```
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs = Lhs>
struct GenerateOtherComparisonsFromLessThan
{
    constexpr friend bool operator>(const Rhs& p_rhs, const Lhs& p_lhs)
    {
        return p_lhs < p_rhs;
    }
    //and rest of other comparison operators
};

struct InstantiateTestComparisons : GenerateOtherComparisonsFromLessThan<Test>
{};
```

But it looks like these overloads are not taken(at least on gcc 8.3 [on ideone](https://ideone.com/L6JSle)).

Comment: Seems like you are trying to do something similar to [the thing this person did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59594322/export-friend-from-template-to-global-namespace). Not the same question, but the answer is very similar ultimately.

Comment: If you are using C++ before C++20, you might want to look at `std::rel_ops`.    However that is deprecated in C++20 (i.e. marked for potential removal from a future standard) in favour of the spaceship operator.

Comment: I dont understand what `InstantiateTestComparisons` and `GenerateOtherComparisonsFromLessThan` are good for. afaik friends are not inherited and why not just declare the operators without being befriended to some class?

Comment: I don't get what ```struct InstantiateTestComparisons : GenerateOtherComparisonsFromLessThan<Test>``` is needed for, does namespace does your want to achieve? [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/L8MNT6XObTckSAyP)

Comment: What's the underlying reason of "without using CRTP"?